# How to do induction of set proofs

Tags: logic, proof-writing, induction

I'm not necessarily looking for an answer (since I already have the model answer), but the method behind answering a question like the following and any similar questions. I understand how induction is done, but I struggle with applying it to relatively hard questions to me.

Let A and B be finite sets of cardinality n and m respectively, where n, $m ∈ N>0$.
Show, using induction on n, that there are $m^n$
functions from A to B.

If anyone has any examples of questions like this they want to share please do so.

Answer (score 1):

If we have $1$ element, we have $m$ choices to map it to an element of $B$. So, the formula $m^n$ is true for $n=1$

Assume that we have $m^n$ possible maps , if we have $n$ elements. If we have one more element ($n+1$ elements), for every of the $m^n$ maps, we have again $m$ choices to map the $n+1$ th element. So, we have $m^n\cdot m=m^{n+1}$ possible maps completing the proof.

Comment: Do you know of any other questions similar to this that include things like sets. I have this one which completely baffles me, Let A be a set of size n, where n is an integer. Prove by induction that |{x ⊆ A | |x| = 2}| =
n(n−1)/2.  I have the model answer I just don't understand the method behind it

Comment: @john The combinatorical way is to calculate the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, which is also sometimes called "$choose(n,2)$" and denotes the number of possibilities to choose $2$ out of $n$. But why not solve this provlem without any induction ? If we choose the first element, we have $n$ choices and for the second we have $n-1$ choices (no matter what we have chosen for the first element). Since the order does not matter, we have to divide by $2$ because we counted every pair twice.

Comment: If you do want to apply induction, add an element. Now, we have $n$ new possibilities, so we have $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+n=\frac{n^2-n+2n}{2}=\frac{n^2+n}{2}=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ possibilities.